# Android edittext breaks the keyboard when it scrolls out of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a couple of `EditText` elements under each other for a form, this is scrollable because of the height of the form. When you focus on a `EditText` and start scrolling the page, the keyboard breaks. You need to click on the `EditText` to be able to start typing again.

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edittext"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
   android:drawablePadding="32dp"
   android:hint="My Hint"
   style="@style/customstyle"
   />
```

My custom style:

```
<style name="customstyle">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:minLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">text|textCapSentences</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/custom_accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/customstyle_edittext</item>
    <item name="android:elevation" tools:targetApi="lollipop">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Does any one have a solution?

**EDIT:**
The keyboard breaking means: The keyboard is fully functional except for the fact that it won't output into the `EditText`. So you have a collapsed keyboard while it has lost focus on the `EditText`

Comment: Please explain what " the keyboard breaks" means. Is it closing or giving error?

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül edited question

Comment: Do you have any OnFocusChangeListener to handle focus changes on EditText?

Comment: @OğuzhanDöngül nope, it is probably an android bug.